# How do I save values from the child view controllers of a UIPageViewController to use elsewhere in an app?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` containing multiple view controllers each with questions for the user to respond to. Once these questions are answered I want to save the values somewhere locally so I can later create a PDF populated with these values. What is the best way to do this? Would I use NSUserDefaults?

Comment: My 2 cents: if it's like 4-5 answers that are simple numbers/strings true/false, you could probably get away with using UserDefaults though that's not the usual job of those... Otherwise look into CoreData structures.

Comment: Your job is to design your app architecture in such a way that if there is data to be passed around / stored, you can do so. Use user defaults if this is a user default, i.e. something to be saved persistently. If it is merely data to be passed around, store it in an instance property of some object that you can always get a reference to. Could be the page view controller itself, or its parent if it has one, or the app delegate, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want the data to persist. If you want the data to persist the life of the user, even if the app is deleted from the device, you would obviously need to store it away from the client such as in a database (i.e. Realm, CoreData). If you want the data to persist the life of the app itself, data that you would continue to use to shape the user's experience, you could use `UserDefaults` but that doesn't seem like what you're trying to do. And if you just want the data to persist the life of that instance of the app, store it in regular properties.

I suspect, for whatever reason, the third option would be your choice. If so, I would suggest creating a model object that's as an instance property of the parent view controller (that all page view controllers can reference)...

```
class SurveyAnswers {

    var userName: String?
    var userAge: Int?
    var favoriteSauce: PizzaSauce?
    var livesWithCats: Bool?

}
```

...and simply use the protocol/delegate pattern to pass data from the child to the parent which would update properties in that object (so long as they are updating the same instance of that object). Then, when you're ready to prepare the `PDF` file, simply ask the parent for that object, whose properties have been set by the child view controllers.

And if you're OK with it, you could use the shared `AppDelegate` as a way to store and retrieve this data. I would just caution against making this a habit but depending on your application as a whole, this may be a perfectly acceptable option.

General rule of thumb: set properties in destination objects to pass data forward and use delegates to pass data backward.